# How to change Formatting menu options in redactor?

Tags: redactor

By default, under the Formatting menu (when the button is clicked), there are these options:

```
Normal Text
Quote
Code 
Header 1
Header ...
Header 5
```

I would like to only have these options:

```
Normal Text
Quote
Code
```

Is there any way to do that? I've been scouring the configuration options and haven't been able to find out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olivérs answer is wrong.

You can easily achieve this by doing the following:

```
$('#redactor').redactor({
    formattingTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'pre']
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EkM4A/

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the only way to achieve this is to [decorate](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#decoratorpatternjavascript) your redactor instance before init and overwrite the default toolbar setting in redactor.

You can see a working POC here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zmetser/7m3f9/

And the code below:

```js
$(function() {
    // Decorate redactor Object before init
    $.Redactor.fn = (function () {
        var toolbarInitOriginal = this.toolbarInit;
        // Create a new toolbarInit method which suits our needs
        this.toolbarInit = function (lang) {
            // Grab the default toolbar...
            var toolbar = toolbarInitOriginal(lang);
            // ...and overwrite the formatting dropdown menu
            toolbar.formatting.dropdown = {
                p: {
                    title: lang.paragraph,
                    func: 'formatBlocks'
                },
                blockquote: {
                    title: lang.quote,
                    func: 'formatQuote',
                    className: 'redactor_format_blockquote'
                },
                pre: {
                    title: lang.code,
                    func: 'formatBlocks',
                    className: 'redactor_format_pre'
                },
            };

            return toolbar;
        };

        return this;
    }.call($.Redactor.fn));

    // Init redactor
    $('#redactor').redactor({
        buttons: ['link', 'formatting', 'html']
    });
});
```